# Use curl and key-file (crt, der, txt)

Tags: curl, openssl, private-key

my client gave me a *.crt-file, a *.der-file and a *.txt file, als a key in order to send files per POST. I am using curl in order to send the files, but I couldn't figure out, how. Sadly I do not know much about keys and so on, do you know, what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $options = array(   CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                CURLOPT_SSLCERT => 'cert', 
                CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD => 'cert pass',
                CURLOPT_URL => "whatever",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields
            );
    $options[CURLOPT_SSLKEY] = 'whatever';
    $options[CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE] = 'PEM';
    $options[CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD] = 'pass'; // if needed
    }
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)) die('Curl error: '.curl_error($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
```